# Accessing QGIS program settings programmatically?

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to temporarily enable the option in QGIS using PyQt4 to suppress the attribute dialog popup after a feature is added. I found an example in the [cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/settings.html) but it doesn't indicate how to get to existing settings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The procedure is exactly the same. The settings are not documented, so you have to look them up in the code. For your purpose this is `/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog`

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings

# get user defined current setting
disableDialog = QSettings().value( '/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog')
# override setting
QSettings().setValue( '/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', True )

# do your processing here...

# restore setting
QSettings().setValue( '/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', disableDialog )
```

Comment: The API documentation for QSettings at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html mentions a function allKeys() which can be used to get a list of all settings keys. This could potentially be used to create something like the about:config view in Firefox, to get an easy overview of all settings.

Comment: Matthias, I feel like you are following me!
Should the last line have 'True' as the last parameter or 'disableDialog'?

Comment: I follow the [qgis tag](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis)  and answer questions if it doesn't take me a lot of time or if they sound interesting. The last line restores the original user setting retrieved above.

Comment: From now on I will make sure I make all my questions short and easy then... I just played with the code and see now, thanks.

Comment: I prefer the other way: make them interesting :) you are welcome.

Comment: How would I do the same thing to access layer properties? Again, the cookbook isn't very clear

Comment: As said, the settings are not documented, so you will have to look up these kind of things in the source code.