# How can i change vertex option programmatically using python in QGis?

Tags: qgis, python, vertices

I want to activate the option "Show markers only for selected features" in Setting-> options->vertex markers ,using python.
does anyone know if i can do it programmatically ?
i attached a photo of the ui and i market the option,[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Matthias Kuhn answer of this undocumented feature in [How do I access QGIS program settings programmatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80025/how-do-i-access-qgis-program-settings-programmatically) I got to this:

Get all keys from setting in Python console with:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
print QSettings().allKeys()
```

In a texteditor searched the result for digitizing and found digitizing/marker_only_for_selected

Using this from Python:

```
# Get user defined current setting
markersOnlyForSelected = QSettings().value(u'/qgis/digitizing/Qgis/digitizing/marker_only_for_selected')

# override setting
QSettings().setValue(u'/qgis/digitizing/Qgis/digitizing/marker_only_for_selected', True)

# do your work here...

# restore setting
QSettings().setValue(u'/qgis/digitizing/Qgis/digitizing/marker_only_for_selected', markersOnlyForSelected)
```

Strangely this does not change the value in the QGIS Options dialog, but I guess it does work in code; The QSetting values changes must be in memory only.