# Finding QSettings keys from source code?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qt

I'm looking to change a number of QGIS settings with a python script. Whilst I can find references to some specific keys through various questions/answers on StackExchange, I can't find a method to actually look these up myself.

The question  [How do I access QGIS program settings programmatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80025/how-do-i-access-qgis-program-settings-programmatically) indicates that I need to go into the source code to look these up. However, I'm only a novice with this scripting stuff, and don't really know where to start or what to look for.

Can you provide a generalised set of steps for finding these keys in the source code?

Comment: Your question is broad, what specific setting are you interested in?  See, https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/settings.html

Comment: @artwork21 Right now I'm interested in toggling "Auto Open Form". However, what I'm really after is a method for answering this question myself (if that makes sense). Then I won't have to post another question on SE the next time I want to find a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [QSettings::allKeys()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#allKeys) method by first importing it:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
```

---

Then

- To get a list of current keys:

  ```
  QSettings().allKeys()
  ```
- To print all keys individually (for readability):

  ```
  for keys in QSettings().allKeys():
      print keys
  ```
- To search for a specific key:

  ```
  for keys in QSettings().allKeys():
      if 'Qgis' in keys:
          print keys
  ```