# Pyqgis Qgis2 override Processing framework settings doesn't work

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

Inside my Python plugin (qgis2.18) I use some Processing algorithms.

I'm trying to override the Processing setting that allows using only the selected features.
 I' want to set it to **False** and following [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80025/accessing-qgis-program-settings-programmatically#80028) I use that code inside my plugin before running Processing algs:

```
QSettings().setValue('/processing/configuration/use_selected', False)
```

Unfortunately after running my plugin Processing algorithms still working only with selected features.
But if I check Qgis settings I correctly see that :
 [image]

Some hints about where I'm wrong?


**Edit:**
I noticed that inside Processing own properties the checkbox  is still checked (sorry for Italian menu) and I need to restart Qgis for applying changes.
[image]

Comment: Does it work if you restart QGIS?

Comment: Oh yes. Very disappointing. I can't ask to my users to restart Qgis... I even noticed that inside Processing own properties the checkbox is still checked after running my plugin. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following which should change the settings directly within the processing framework (which can be seen in the properties window):

```
import processing
processing.ProcessingConfig.setSettingValue('USE_SELECTED', False)
```

Comment: Oh man, it works. You've saved my day again.

Comment: @OscarCampo - Most welcome, glad it helped :)